# Unable to see Settings & Administrator tab on SonarQube dashboard

Tags: android, ios, virtualmachine, sonarqube

Environment - Mac

I have configured SonarQube earlier, after that various other configuration might removed my admin user or something happen. But today I am not able to access my admin account/user.

Any one have idea how to regain the not only access but also admin user because I mentioned earlier, Settings tab is not visible on Sonar dashboard!

Answer (score 1):

As per [SonarQube documentation](https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/instance-administration/security/) you have two options:

a) in case you have forgot your admin password

Execute this query on database for SonarQube to set password back to 'admin' for user admin.

```
update users set crypted_password = '$2a$12$uCkkXmhW5ThVK8mpBvnXOOJRLd64LJeHTeCkSuB3lfaR2N0AYBaSi', salt=null, hash_method='BCRYPT' where login = 'admin'
```

b) in case you have deleted / modified admin user account

Execute this query and grand admin permission (do not forget to change 'mylogin' to corresponding account):

```
INSERT INTO user_roles(user_id, role) VALUES ((select id from users where login='mylogin'), 'admin');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can only see these options if you have admin.

Do you have it configured to use AD credentials ? its possible to lock yourself out if AD goes wrong (e.g. machine account expired or AD server not available)

Its a very secure system to you will probably have to reinstall if you have lost the admin password.